# Number of ways to distribute 3 elements to 4 people

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am having trouble finding a strategy to answer the question about the number of ways to distribute 3 elements to 4 people.

The additional conditions are:

- anyone can have all 3 elements
- so some people can get no element at all
- all elements must be distributed

---

I have created a table in the following format and was hoping to approach a general strategy via the solution. So I came up with 10 different possibilities.

Does anyone have a hint/tip for me to get me to a mathematically sound strategy that doesn't amount to mindless counting?

3000
0300
0030
0003
2001
2010
2100
...
...

Comment: Are the elements distinct or identical ?

Comment: Assuming the elements are identical (*as suggested by your count thus far*) see: [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  Assuming they are distinct, very simply choose who gets the "first" element, then choose who gets the "second" element and so on... and apply rule of product for a total of $4\times 4\times 4=64$

Comment: There are $4^3$ maps.

Comment: The punchline is to compare your list you've written to this list:  ...|||  |...||  ||...|  |||...  ..|||.  ..||.|   ..|.|| and so on.  The meaning should hopefully be clear.  The dots (*or stars*) will represent the elements.  The lines (*or bars*) will be used to partition the stars into different piles, where the stars to the left of the first bar will go to the first person, the stars between the first and second bar go to the second person, the stars between the second and third bar go to the third person, and so on... Your question boils down to what arrangements of stars and bars exist.